# Convert integer value to hexadecimal string

Tags: c, hex

I have an integer returning from a function:

```
   int a = func();
```

For example, `a = 236`.

I need to treat this as a hexadecimal representation of an integer, and store its *decimal* representation in another variable, so that when printed like so:

```
  printf("%x", variable)
```

...the output should be:

```
 236
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `int a = 0x236` would seem to achieve the result you want.

Comment: You mean `int a = 0xec;` ?

Comment: @ring0 No I need it like 0x236. And also I am getting this value to the variable from a function.

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: You're confusing the value of a number with its representation. This is common initiate mistake.

Comment: I rewrote the question and the title, to better match the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i've understood what you need, this little code snippet will do it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char num[128];
    int a=236;
    int hex;

    sprintf(num, "0x%d", a);

    sscanf(num, "%x", &hex);

    printf("Hex: %x\n", hex);
}
```

output is

```
Hex: 236
```

Answer (score 4):

All the values will be stored in binary format only. If you want to print the value in decimal formal print using `%d` format string or if you want to print the value in hexa decimal then print using `%x`.

Sameway we can assign the values in decimal and hexadecimal format also.

```
int a = 236;
int b = 0x236;
printf("%d", a); //it will print 236
printf("%x", a); //it will print EC
printf("%d", b); //it will print 566
printf("%x", b); //it will print 236
```

We can print the stored binary values in octal formal also using `%o` format string.

Comment: Values are stored as binary, not hexadecimal.

Comment: updated the answer. Actually what I meant was, it will not store ASCII value of `2` `3` and `6` in 3 bytes for the value `236`